# Cannot read property Global Variables Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, global-variables

I have a files structure like this:

[image: file structure]

In `main.js` I declared a global variable api_url:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
Vue.prototype.$api_url = 'https://api.url/v1/'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

In `AuthServices.js` I try to read global variable

```
import axios from 'axios'

const apiUsers = axios.create({
  baseURL: this.$api_url,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  timeout: 10000,
})
```

The app crash with this message:

> ```
> AuthServices.js?3d37:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$api_url' of undefined
>     at eval (AuthServices.js?3d37:5)
>     at Module../src/services/AuthServices.js (app.js:1733)
> ```

I will apreciare any help.

Comment: You assign `$api_url` to `Vue`, but try to read it from `this`?

Comment: Sorry I am new to vue js, I did not understand your question well, what do you mean by but try to read it from, Thanks for your fast reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.$api_url` only work on vue components, where this is linked to the Vue reference.
You can export the Vue app on your `main.js` and then import it on `AuthServices.js` to get the reference to $api_url.

It's more simple to create enviroment variables and then use on both files, see: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes